# Pyspark error VectorAssembler: Data type array <string> of column temp_array is not supported

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, vectorization

I have a big dataframe df that looks like:

| id | temp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [[20,29,30,40], [26,29,31,42], [30,30,32,42], [40,31,32,43]] |
| 2 | [[18,25,37,41],[20,29,31,42],[25,32,30,40],[30,31,32,43]] |
| ....... | ..... |

I would like to cluster the temperature in groups using KNN. The temp column is a string, and for my proposal, I should convert it to an array first and then to a vector. So I was tring:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = (df.select("id",
          F.split(F.col("temp"), "\\[]").alias("temp_array")))
```

and so I get the schema

```
|--id:string (nullable = true)
 |-- temp_array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Now I would like to vectorize it and I was using the VectorAssambel method, but I am getting an error:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["temper_array"], outputCol="temperature_vector")
df_vekt = assembler.transform(df2)
```

*Fail to execute line 4: df_vekt = assembler.transform(df2)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type array string of column temp_array is not supported.*

I don't know how to go further. I was also trying to convert from the beginning of the string to an integer, but didn't work as well because I got null values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify what you vector needs to look like? Do you want vectors of 4 dimensions? Or 16 dimensions?

Comment: Hi @Koedlt, the vektor should have the dimension of all the values in temp col. Each of the values in [] has a meaning [ time in sek, first temp, second tem, outer temp]. The problem is that I dont have the same dim for each col.

Comment: Your `temp` column seems to be an array of arrays, but you seem to want to make vectors out of an element of each array. Do I understand it correctly that your first vector is `[20,29,30,40]`? And your second one is `[26,29,31,42]`?

Comment: No I would like to let it as it is because each array on the array has a timestamp and the values that was taken in this timestamp and this for an id. This means when for exp I am boiling water I get [[ 30 sek, 20 °C, 32°C, 19°C] , [34 sek, 22 °C, 36°C, 19°C]] etc. I would like vektorize the array as they are. and I think the problem at all is that the elemnts of the aray are strings if you see it on the data schema.

Comment: Ok well it's not really clear to me what you want then. Let's talk in terms of linear algebra: how many dimensions should your vectors have? AKA, what is the dimensionality of the vector space in which you want to create your clusters?